# Coverage can't cover the public static void main method

Tags: java, code-coverage

Using Junit coverage, it can't cover public static void main method. How can I cover it?

Comment: What coverage tool are you using to find the coverage of your junit tests?

Answer (score 4):

After making sure it's testable just call it as any other public static method:

```
YourClass.main(new String[] {"parameter 1", "parameter 2"});
```

And assert the following state afterwards.

Comment: I had wrote codes like yours, but coverage reports are displayed as you test didn't cover the main method.

Comment: Could you step through your test? If it does invoke the main method then the problem lies in the test coverage tool which excludes static methods.

Comment: Unless you declared the main with variable arguments, shouldn't it be `YourClass.main(new String[] { "param 1", "param 2" });` ?

Comment: yes,"main(String[] args)". and invoke it in testcase like yours

Answer (score 0):

Because it does not return anything, you cannot check the output. But what does it do? If it calls another method the write a test for that method. If it doesn't call other methods, then write a test for that.

Comment: the objective of this issue is cover all lines of main method. i can't modify the content of main method. i had call the main method in junit test, but why the coverage can't cover it.